# .Net assembly for db migration can't be registered if com-interop is set under project properties build in vs

Tags: c#, dll, entity-framework-core, nuget-package, com-interop

I want to create a C# .Net dll as Add-In for Enterprise Architect in Visual Studio.
This dll has to be registered for com-interop to be used by Enterprise Achitect.

Within this dll I also want to do a database migration with code first and nuget package microsoft.entityframework.core.
This database migration works fine with the paket manager console in visual studio if the com-interop checkbox in project properties build is un-checked.
If it's checked my dll can't compile.
The error message is:

> The assembly "... .dll" can not be registered. The method "DisposeAsync" in type "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext" of assembly "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore, Version 3.1.8..."
> has no implementation.

In my original code I have no functions with any kind of Dispose or similar. It's a simple project with a few lines of code.
I tried to manage it in nuget package manager with older versions of Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore, but it didn't help.
Also I had overwritten the DisposeAsync function within my code, but this didn't also help.

The relevant code is within the context class the line with DbContext:

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace ...

{

        public class .. : DbContext
   
        {
```

In Google I couldn't find anything so please help me.

Answer (score 0):

The problem may be caused by different assembly versions in your project and in product where yours add-in is integrated.

Example:

- You are using some NuGet package named System.dll version 2.0 in your project
- Product where Add-In is to be installed using the same assembly for it's own purpose but with different version (System.dll version 1.0).
- When your Add-In is loaded to target product it loads all necessary referenced assemblies, BUT if assembly with the same name is already loaded, it uses loaded assembly (not the actual you used while building).
- If versions differs you would get some strange exceptions like the one in your question or any other strange things.

Try to discover which assembly version you need to change in your project to evade from dll versions mismatch. Try to use FusionLog to investigate. Pay attention that the problem dll may be not Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore but any of the assemblies EntityFramework depends on. Unfortunately there's no direct instruction how to solve your problem. Adding assemblies to the 3rd party assembly dynamically is quite a tricky thing.